# export from Illustrator to PDF - text not selectable

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, pdf, export

We need to export a 2-page file from Illustrator CS6 to PDF.

The issue is that when a user opens this PDF file (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC) they can't select any of the text (Selection tool for text and images).

We can't discover what we are doing wrong.

Can you help us?

Comment: You didn't create outlines prior to making the PDF by any chance did you?